# Prevent Xcode from copying assets every time while debugging?

Tags: xcode, debugging

I have a project with huge amount of assets. I am in a point that I need to check the app with all the assets.

The problem is that xCode is copying al the assets to the devices, even if no change has been made. that slows down the building and the debugging process is a nightmare.

Is there a way to "ask" xCode not to copy those assets every time ?